# Formula field based on Picklist value

Tags: salesforce

I need to create a formula field based on another picklist Field.Based on the value available in picklist need to populate same value in formula field.Here in picklist field contains 30values.Please suggest how to implement this

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at relevant functions from the [Formula Operators and Functions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions.htm&type=0) reference that apply to picklists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
TEXT(Picklist field API Name)
```

Or Check this
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?err=1&id=tips_for_using_picklist_formula_fields.htm&type=5